# Change loaded phtml file using store code from layout xml

Tags: magento-1, xml

This is my code from my local.xml:

This is the block:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="core/template" name="product.delivery" template="experius/statichtml/delivery.phtml" after="-">
             <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
             <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Test</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

and

```
<STORE_mystore_code>
        <catalog_product_view>
            <reference name="product.info">
                <reference name="product.delivery">
                    <action method="setTemplate"><file>experius/statichtml/delivery_de.phtml</file></action>
                </reference>
            </reference>
        </catalog_product_view>        
<STORE_mystore_code>
```

My store code is 100% correct. Why I don't get the content of the delivery_de.phtml file ? Right now I got the content of the delivery.phtml file.Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually using the  doesn't work for me, so I cam up with another solution:
   - to create a block and the template using the store code.

This is my laypout xml part:

```
<block type="mynamespace_mymodule/tabs" name="product.delivery" after="-">
     <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
     <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Test</value></action>
</block>
```

This is my block:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $currentStoreCode =  substr(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode(), -2 );
        $this->setTemplate('mynamespace_mymodule/tabs/delivery/delivery_'.$currentStoreCode.'.phtml');
    }
}
```

In my case the store code are like: `storecode_de, storecode_at, storecode_ro`

So I created for each store a phtml file like: `delivery_de, delivery_at, etc`.

I had some custom reason to do that, so don't judge me:)